# How to bind incoming udp client with socket in UDP server programming?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

So far, all sample codes of UDP server use the client ip/port from recvfrom() function in C lang.
I want to use exclusive udp client socket in UDP server app. just like socket fd after accept() call in tcp server app.
Is there a way to bind the UDP client with socket?

Comment: Why? You only need one UDP socket in a server. Don't waste resources, or coding time or space.

Comment: UDP is connectionless. Unlike TCP, there is no need to use a separate socket per client in a UDP server. You have to use `bind()` to specify the local IP/port the server listens on, but you can send replies using the same UDP socket that received datagrams. Use `sendto()` to specify which client IP/port to send to. Typically this is the IP/port reported by `recvfrom()`, unless client and server agree that replies are sent somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

UDP is a connectionless protocol so it won't receive from a specific socket.  So you'll get information about the client in each datagram that's sent.

Comment: 'Won't receive from a specific socket' is either wrong or meaningless. and there are two *non sequiturs* here.

Comment: not that it won't receive from a specific socket but that there will not be a file descriptor created for a new connected socket.  As a result, you'll still need the packet header will still need src information.